# cantidad de islas de un mapa - Ayuda con char ** filas y columnas

Tags: c++

La salida que estoy teniendo, se encuentra al final de todo (está la salida esperada y la salida de mi código).

- PRECONDICION:  recibe un mapa representado por una matriz, de dimensiones col x fil, en la cual 'A' representa un lugar donde hay agua, y 'T' donde hay tierra
- POSTCONDICION:  devuelve la cantidad de islas del mapa. Una isla es un conjunto de tierras adyacentes, ortogonal o diagonal (puede ser una sola).

Los indices del mapa recibido se deben usar como mapa[c][f] donde c y f corresponden a la columna y fila respectivamente. La matriz recibida debe ser retornada sin cambios.

#### Ejemplo 1

```
Entrada: (['T','A','T','A'], 4, 1)
Retorno: 2
```

#### Ejemplo 2

```
Entrada: (['T','T','A'
           'A','A','T'
           'A','A','A'
           'T','T','A'], 3, 4)
Retorno: 2
```

SALIDAS (ESPERADA VS LA DE MI CODIGO)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que he tratado de hacer:

```
int islas(char** mapa, int col, int fil)
   void borrarIsla(char** mapa, int col, int fil, int pCol, int pFil) {
    mapa[pCol][pFil] = 'A';
    int vectPosC[8] = { 1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1 };
    int vectPosF[8] = { 0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1 };
    int u, v;
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        u = pCol;
        v = pFil;
        u += vectPosC[k];
        v += vectPosF[k];
        if (dentro(col, fil, u, v) && mapa[u][v] == 'T') {
            borrarIsla(mapa, col, fil, u, v);
        }
    }
}

bool dentro(int col, int fil, int u, int v) {
    return u >= 0 && u < col && v >= 0 && v < fil;
}

char** copiaListaStr(char** listPalabras, int largoVec) {
    if (largoVec > 0) {
        char** aux = new char* [largoVec];
        for (int i = 0; i < largoVec; i++)
        {
            int largoPalabra = largoStr(listPalabras[i]);
            aux[i] = copiarStr(listPalabras[i], largoPalabra);
        }
        return aux;
    }
    return NULL;
}


char* copiarStr(char* palabra, int largo) {
    char* aux = new char[largo + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++)
    {
        aux[i] = palabra[i];
    }
    aux[largo] = '\0';
    return aux;
}

int largoStr(char* vec) {
    int i = 0;
    while (vec[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int islas(char** mapa, int col, int fil) {
    int cont = 0;
    char** mapAux = copiaListaStr(mapa, col);
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++) {
            if (mapAux[j][i] == 'T') {
                cont++;
                borrarIsla(mapAux, col, fil, j, i);
            }
        }
        delete[] mapAux[j];
    }
    delete[] mapAux;
    return cont;
    
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Juan, recuerda que el titulo de la pregunta es importante ya que los miembros de la comunidad pueden interesarse o no en abrir tu pregunta de acuerdo a su titulo en el listado de preguntas, te sugiero algo más descriptivo relacionado a tu pregunta, recuerda lo que sugiere el documento [ask], "El título es la primera cosa que los que potenciales contestadores verán, y si tu título no es interesante, ellos no leerán el resto.", saludos!.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys. Ya la edité. Saludos.